# Optimizing nested "Select Distinct" query

Tags: optimization, sql, mysql

I am using the following query which is causing issues. Note following points:

1. I am using 4 tables in this query:

   1. `message_share`
   2. `messages`
   3. `myusertable`
   4. `friends`
2. What I am trying to do in this query is to display messages, and share messages of users who are friend with each other.

This is similar to Facebook wall where they display friends' wall data.

The problem is only `myusertable` is causing the issue. It increase the load too much,  even to where the query can timeout.

When I remove `myusertable` from this query then it works fine, the use of `myusertable` is to fetch user full name. Everything else we are doing with `userid` and does not need  `myusertable`. For the sole purpose of getting user full name are we using `myusertable`.

**The query is**

```
(SELECT DISTINCT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, S.created, M.like_count,M.comment_count,M.share_count, U.username,M.uploads, S.uid_fk AS share_uid,S.ouid_fk AS share_ouid
FROM friends F
LEFT JOIN message_share S ON S.ouid_fk <> F.friend_two
LEFT JOIN messages M ON M.msg_id = S.msg_id_fk AND M.uid_fk = S.ouid_fk
LEFT JOIN myusertable U ON U.uid = M.uid_fk AND U.status1='1'
WHERE F.friend_one='199095' AND F.role='fri'
GROUP BY msg_id
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, M.like_count,M.comment_count,M.share_count, U.username,M.uploads, '0' AS share_uid, '0' AS share_ouid
FROM friends F
LEFT JOIN messages M ON M.uid_fk = F.friend_two
LEFT JOIN myusertable U ON U.uid = M.uid_fk AND U.status1='1'
WHERE F.friend_one='199095'
GROUP BY msg_id
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10)
```

Is there anything that I can do with `myusertable` to make this query faster?

Comment: Welcome, 1) what does queries do ? 2) where is the schema/DDL code ? 3) is the [tag:php] necessary ?

Comment: these qeries fetching data from messages and get data of user id who posted the message and also check for comments on that msg. i am new in php mysql so can u tell me abt schema or ddl code how i can get

Comment: schema/DDL is the create queries for the tables

Comment: how i can get this schema or ddl? Which query should i write. also i remove the usertable maping and speed was good.

Comment: Query 1 is unreviewable, since you don't provide `$morequery`. It's also syntactically incorrect; you've got a dangling `LIMIT`. I've taken the liberty of removing it, since leaving it in would make this question entirely off-topic.

Comment: OK wait. i will update wtih correct query.

Comment: you can use mysql workbench, select a table-> right click send to sql editor->create statement, to get the schema/DDL. after that update the question with schema/DDL of related tables.

Comment: i have updated my question and explain what i am trying to do. please check now

Answer (score 2):

## **Nitpicking**

**Aliases/notation**

Single-letter alias names are not very helpful. Aliases should at least give Mr. Maintainer a clue what it stands for. What if you had a table called `family` along with `friends`... would you call it `F2`?

```
FROM friends F
LEFT JOIN message_share S ON S.ouid_fk <> F.friend_two
LEFT JOIN messages M ON M.msg_id = S.msg_id_fk AND M.uid_fk = S.ouid_fk
LEFT JOIN myusertable U ON U.uid = M.uid_fk AND U.status1='1'
```

Also, I find it good practice to use the optional `AS` keyword, just looks better in my opinion. How about:

```
FROM friends AS Frnd
LEFT JOIN message_share AS Share ON Share.ouid_fk <> Frnd.friend_two
LEFT JOIN messages AS Msg ON Msg.msg_id = Share.msg_id_fk AND Msg.uid_fk = Share.ouid_fk
LEFT JOIN myusertable AS User ON User.uid = Msg.uid_fk AND Usr.status1 = '1'
```

**Column names**

Some of your column names are pretty cryptic. I realize you may not have any say into it, but if this is your database you may consider changing names like `ouid_fk` and such to something more meaningful, if a bit more verbose.

**Indentation/spacing**

Use line breaks and indentation to facilitate reading of your queries. Also consistent spacing is an improvement.

```
(SELECT DISTINCT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, S.created, M.like_count,M.comment_count,M.share_count, U.username,M.uploads, S.uid_fk AS share_uid,S.ouid_fk AS share_ouid
```

Why not instead:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT 
  Msg.msg_id, 
  Msg.uid_fk, 
  Msg.message, 
  Share.created, 
  Msg.like_count,
  Msg.comment_count,
  Msg.share_count, 
  Usr.username,
  Msg.uploads, 
  Share.uid_fk AS share_uid,
  Share.ouid_fk AS share_ouid
```

**`INT` in a `VARCHAR` column?**

I find this odd:

```
AND Usr.status1 = '1'
```

To me in a well-designed database, this `status1` column should be `int` (4 bytes), `smallint` (2 bytes) or `tinyint` (1 byte). Not to mention, `status1` is not a very good column name.

## **`SELECT DISTINCT`**

I don't feel that this is needed at all, for a couple of reasons:

1. Do you expect multiple messages to have the same `msg_id`? Wouldn't that completely defeat the purpose of an ID?
2. Your `GROUP BY msg_id` already does this, but it does the work on the result set rather than the source data set, which will likely be much faster.

Here is what I would refactor to. However there is no way for me to test performance since you did not provide DDL or sample data.

```
(SELECT 
  Msg.msg_id, 
  Msg.uid_fk, 
  Msg.message, 
  Share.created, 
  Msg.like_count,
  Msg.comment_count,
  Msg.share_count, 
  Usr.username,
  Msg.uploads, 
  Share.uid_fk AS share_uid,
  Share.ouid_fk AS share_ouid
FROM friends AS Frnd
LEFT JOIN message_share AS Share ON Share.ouid_fk <> Frnd.friend_two
LEFT JOIN messages AS Msg ON Msg.msg_id = Share.msg_id_fk AND Msg.uid_fk = Share.ouid_fk
LEFT JOIN myusertable AS User ON User.uid = Msg.uid_fk AND Usr.status1 = '1'
WHERE Frnd.friend_one='199095' AND Frnd.role='fri'
GROUP BY Msg.msg_id
ORDER BY Share.created DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT 
  Msg.msg_id, 
  Msg.uid_fk, 
  Msg.message, 
  Share.created, 
  Msg.like_count,
  Msg.comment_count,
  Msg.share_count, 
  Usr.username,
  Msg.uploads, 
  Share.uid_fk AS share_uid,
  Share.ouid_fk AS share_ouid
FROM friends AS Frnd
LEFT JOIN message_share AS Share ON Share.ouid_fk <> Frnd.friend_two
LEFT JOIN messages AS Msg ON Msg.msg_id = Share.msg_id_fk AND Msg.uid_fk = Share.ouid_fk
LEFT JOIN myusertable AS User ON User.uid = Msg.uid_fk AND Usr.status1 = '1'
WHERE Frnd.friend_one='199095'
GROUP BY Msg.msg_id
ORDER BY Share.created DESC LIMIT 10)
```

Comment: So this is the final optimize query suggested by you? Should i replace my query with your last query?

Comment: thanks for your rply but here i can not post my db structure. can you provide me your any gmail or skype id where i can take your guidence, i have only 4 query in which i need and i am stuck in those 4 queries from many months. i will be your thankfull. please provide me any chat id

Comment: your suggested query not displaying the data

Comment: I run your query, it run without error but result is same. very slow and timeout

Comment: Your problem might be elsewhere then. I suggest checking the execution plan. From the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 1):

### Non-standard `GROUP BY`

MySQL, with its default settings, is very lenient in interpreting queries that involve a `GROUP BY` clause, to the point where it can accept queries that make no sense at all.  There is a server-wide [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) setting that can be enabled to make MySQL follow the sane, standard behaviour.

Specifically, in both halves of the query, you have used `GROUP BY` with only one attribute (`M.msg_id`), but listed many columns to be selected without the use of aggregate functions.  Assuming that `msg_id` is the primary key of the `messages` table, I could forgive the use of other columns of `M` in the `SELECT` list, such as `M.uid_fk`, `M.message`, etc.  However, it makes no sense to select unaggregated columns of `message_share` and `myusertable`.  Every SQL-compliant database would reject this query on those grounds.

I also do not understand what exactly you intend to accomplish with this query, and therefore cannot offer much advice in optimizing it.

### `OUTER JOIN`

I am suspicious of your use of `LEFT JOIN`.  I believe it is possible to obtain rows that consist entirely of `NULL` values.  Don't write `LEFT JOIN` if you actually mean `INNER JOIN`.

### `UNION` and `LIMIT`

It's not really possible to rewrite the `UNION` in a way that obtains exactly the same results, since you want each half of the query to return ten rows.  If the row count didn't matter, you could extract some of the intermediate joining tables into a subquery.

### `DISTINCT`

Using `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost always a sign that your joins are poorly formulated.  Frequently, phantom rows appear when you perform `JOIN`s when a `WHERE EXISTS` subquery might have been more appropriate.  Unfortunately, I can't offer concrete advice since you didn't include any details about your schema in your question.